# Proving Sturm's separation theorem: if $y_1, y_2$ are fundamental solutions of $y''+py+q=0$, their zeros alternate.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, roots

This is a problem from Braun's Differential Equations book. Let $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ continuous functions and $y_{1}$, $y_{2}$ a fundamental set of solutions of the ODE
\begin{equation}
y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=0
\end{equation}
in the interval $t\in(-\infty,\infty)$. Prove that there is only one zero of $y_{1}$ between two consequtive zeros of $y_{2}$.
Hint: Differentiate the expression $y_{2}/y_{1}$ and use Rolle's theorem.

This is what I have. Let $a,b$ two consecutive zeros of $y_{2}$ with $a<b$. Since $y_{1}$, $y_{2}$ are a fundamental set of solutions, their Wronskian
\begin{equation}
W(y_{1},y_{2})=y_{1}y_{2}'-y_{1}'y_{2}
\end{equation}
 is not zero for all $t$. This implies that neither $a$ or $b$ are zeros of $y_{1}$. Then, I tried to use the hint computing the derivative of $y_{2}/y_{1}$,
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{d}{dt}(y_{2}/y_{1})=W(y_{1},y_{2})/y_{1}^{2}
\end{equation}
but then I have no idea of what to do, thanks for the help.

Comment: Note the Wronskian is nonzero and continuous,  so it is always positive or always negative.   Thus,  so is the derivative of $y_1/y_2$,  so your quotient is monotone.  Not quite sure where to go from there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove both the existence and uniqueness of a zero of $y_1$ between the consecutive zeroes $a,b$ of $y_2$. As you observed, $W$ vanishes nowhere.

For existence, assume for the sake of contradiction that $y_1$ does not vanish on $(a,b)$. Then $z:=y_2/y_1$ is differentiable there, and your calculation shows $z'=W/y_1^2$. By your observation that neither $a$ nor $b$ are zeros of $y_1$, we have $z(a)=z(b)=0$. By Rolle's theorem, there is some place in $(a,b)$ where $z'$, and thus $W$, vanishes. This contradicts the fact that $W$ never vanishes.

For uniqueness, assume $y_1$ has two roots on $(a,b)$, say $c$ and $d$. Apply the same argument above to the reciprocal $z^{-1}=y_1/y_2$ to conclude that $y_2$ must vanish somewhere in $(c,d)\subset(a,b)$, contradicting the fact that $a$ and $b$ are *consecutive* roots of $y_2$.

Comment: FWIW, this is called [Sturm's separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm_separation_theorem).

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot @symplectomorphic. I did not knew about Sturm's separation theorem

Comment: Beautiful written proof. Made me smile.